# How to capture text between two markers?

Tags: regex

For clarity, I have created this:

http://rubular.com/r/ejYgKSufD4

My strings:

```
http://blablalba.com/foo/bar_soap/foo/dir2
http://blablalba.com/foo/bar_soap/dir
http://blablalba.com/foo/bar_soap
```

My Regular expression:

```
\/foo\/(.*)
```

This returns:

```
/foo/bar_soap/dir/dir2
/foo/bar_soap/dir
/foo/bar_soap
```

But I only want

```
/foo/bar_soap
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? As illustrated above, I want everything after foo up until the first forward slash.

Thanks in advance.

Edit. I only want the text after `foo` until until the next forward slash after. Some directories may also be named as `foo` and this would render incorrect results. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` will match anything, so you should change it to `[^/]` (not slash) instead:

```
\/foo\/([^\/]*)
```

Some of the other answers use `+` instead of `*`. That might be correct depending on what you want to do. Using `+` forces the regex to match at least one non-slash character, so this URL would not match since there isn't a trailing character after the slash:

http://blablalba.com/foo/

Using `*` instead would allow that to match since it matches "zero or more" non-slash characters. So, whether you should use `+` or `*` depends on what matches you want to allow.

***Update***

If you want to filter out [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) too, you could also filter against `?`, which must come at the front of all query strings. (I think the examples you posted below are actually missing the leading `?`):

```
\/foo\/([^?\/]*)
```

However, rather than rolling out your own solution, it might be better to just use [`split` from the URI module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-split). You could use `URI::split` to get the *path* part of the URL, and then use `String#split` split it up by `/`, and grab the first one. This would handle all the weird cases for URLs. One that you probably haven't though of yet is a URL with a specified *fragment*, e.g.:

http://blablalba.com/foo#bar

You would need to add `#` to your filtered-character class to handle those as well.

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Will accept in 7 minutes. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Zero or more is what I want to match. Thanks for expanding the explanation. I've just tested it against my complete data set and it's returned the matches I want :)

Comment: /foo/bar_soap&stupidarg=cheese - any ideas how I can filter out up until the &stupidarg=cheese? So again, using your example returns /foo/bar_soap&stupidarg=cheese but I just want /foo/bar_soap

Comment: Ah, yes, query strings... You might want to just use the [URI module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) if you want to handle everything, but I'll give another couple of options for the regex.

Comment: \/foo\/([^&\/]*) has worked perfectly! I'm not actually writing ruby, that's just the best regular expression tester that I found online. Cheers, VERY HELPFUL! :)

Comment: Oh, that explains why you didn't tag your question as Ruby. Whatever language you're using, I bet there's a library for handling URIs, and you could do something similar to what I suggested above. But, if the ad-hoc regex works for your purposes, then that's great too!

Answer (score 1):

`\/foo\/([^\/]+)`

`[^\/]+` gives you a series of characters that are not a forward slash.

the parentheses cause the regex engine to store the matched contents in a group `([^\/]+)`, so you can get `bar_soap` out of the entire match of `/foo/bar_soap`

For example, in javascript you would get the matched group as follows:

```
regexp = /\/foo\/([^\/]+)/ ;
match = regexp.exec("/foo/bar_soap/dir");
console.log(match[1]);  // prints bar_soap
```

Comment: This works, but needs further tweaking. If I have /foo/bar_soap/foo, foo is also returned. I only want the text after foo up until the first marker (rather than ignoring the forward slashes).

Comment: it sounds like you are taking the whole match, but should be grabbing just the first matched group, which would be `bar_soap` in your example.  What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regular expression

```
/\/foo\/([^\/]+)/
```